# My netgear DGN3500 support VDSL?

Tags: router, adsl-router, vdsl

Does my netgear DGN3500 support VDSL ? I tried to google but could not find an answer . I need that to upgrade to new higher speed from my ISP.

Comment: Short answer: no

Comment: Yes. The router spec says "ADSL2+" not "VDSL/ADSL" as do other Netgear routers.

Comment: To expand on @DavidPostill comment - VDSL is a newer and faster technology then ADSL (but based on it and backwards compatible).  A VDSL modem can typically do ADSL but an ADSL modem can't do VDSL.